# How can I send a file with socket in multiple messages?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I'm new using Node.js and Zmq. I have to send a file of 138KB in 1KB fragments.

I have a client. The client receive in konsole args the path of the file and then the server read that file and send to client. The problem is that when I send the file is sent only in 1 fragment.

Why is this, and how can I solve it?

Here is the code for server:

```
var zmq         = require("zmq");
var rp          = zmq.socket("rep");
var pussh       = zmq.socket('push');
var fs          = require("fs");
var i           = 0, j = 0;                             // for index of sendings
var size        = 0.0;
var file        = '';
var buf         = new Buffer(1024101024);               // Buffer BIG with all the file
var sendingBuff = new Buffer(1024);                     // Buffer 1KB what it's send to client

rp.bind("tcp://*:8000", function(err) {                 // REP.bind() rep-req connection
    if(err) throw err;
});

pussh.bind("tcp://*:8001", function(err) {              // PUSH.bind() push-pull conection
    if(err) throw err; 
});

rp.on("message",function(msg,err) {                     // sending function
    if(err) throw err;
    file = '' + msg;
    console.log('I have received: ' + file);
    size = getFilesizeInbytes(file);                    // get the size of the file
    buf  = fs.readFileSync(file);                       // get the file in a buffer
    while (i < size){                                   // WHILE(){ the send loop }
        if (j < size){
            sendingBuff = buf.toString(i,j);            //         here I have an error after send the file:
                                                        //         events.js:72 throw er; Unhandled 'error' event
            pussh.send(sendingBuff);
            i = i + 1024;
            j = j + 1024;
            }
        else{
            j = size;
            sendingBuff = buf.toString(i,j);
            pussh.send(sendingBuff);
            i = size + 1;
            }
        }
    pussh.send("ok");
    rp.send("ok");
});

function getFilesizeInbytes(filename) {                // function what obtains the file size
   var stats           = fs.statSync(filename);
   var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];
   fileSizeInBytes     = fileSizeInBytes;
   return fileSizeInBytes;
}
```

And here is the code for the client:

```
var zmq         = require("zmq");
var rq          = zmq.socket("req");
var pull        = zmq.socket('pull');
var argv        = process.argv;
var file        = argv[2];
var fs          = require("fs");
var counter     = 0;
var wData       = '';
var buffer      = new Buffer (1025);
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('local');

rq.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8000");                    // REQ.connect()->REP rep-req connection

pull.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8001");                  // PULL.connect()->PUSH push-pull connection

rq.send(file);                                         // send the name of the file from the client -> server

rq.on("ok",function(msg){                              // when I receive on REQ "ok" ends
    console.log('End of task');
    rq.end();
});

rq.on("end",function(msg){
    process.exit();
});

pull.on("message",function(msg) {
    console.log('received: ' + ++counter);            // control the name of buffer received
    wData = msg.toString();                           // convert buffer msg into String
    writeStream.write(wData);                         // write the data
    writeStream.on('ok', function () {                // when I receive "ok" ends
        writeStream.end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your problem is not with the ZeroMQ part

Upon a hopefully successful `.readFileSync()` without an encoding specified, your **`buf`** holds something like the following object:

```
<Buffer 54 65 73 74 69 6e 67 20 4e 6f 64 65 2e 6a 73 20 72 65 61 64 46 69 6c 65 28 29>
```

from which you start trying to re-read in a **`while(){}`**-ed loop by an instruction to:

```
sendingBuff = buf.toString(i,j);
```

where you may note, that both initial & updated values are not as you might want:

```
buf.toString( [encoding == 'utf-8'], [start], [end] )
buf.toString(                              0,     0 );        // 1st call -- ZERO BYTEs
buf.toString(                           1024,  1024 );        // 2nd call -- ZERO BYTEs
buf.toString(                           2048,  2048 );        // 3rd call -- ZERO BYTEs
buf.toString(                           3072,  3072 );        // 4th call -- ZERO BYTEs
```